# Python Сложение двух значений и запись их в файл

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Моя программа генерирует случайное число и записывает его в файл. В этом файле у меня уже есть значение, например 4. Как мне записать случайное число и прибавить значение которое уже было в файле?

Мой код не прибавляет старое значение, а записывает только случайное число

Код:

```
randval = random.randint(3, 20)
with open('values.bin', 'r') as f:
       f.seek(0)
       old_val = f.readline()
       old_data = f.read()

       new_data = old_data.replace(old_val, randval)

       with open('values.bin', 'w') as f:
            f.write(new_data)
            f.close()
```

Comment: а где у вас прибавление в коде? #Слово replace имеет дословный перевод «заменять», так что название метода точно описывает его назначение. С помощью replace можно заменить часть строки или её всю на другую строку.

Comment: Два числа складываются оператором ``+``

Answer (score 1):

Покритикую, пожалуй.

```
randval = random.randint(3, 20)
with open('values.bin', 'r') as f:
       f.seek(0)
```

Вы только что открыли файл, он и так на позиции `0`, зачем вы делаете `seek(0)`?

```
       old_val = f.readline()
       old_data = f.read()
```

Зачем вы двумя разными способами читаете из файла? Выберите что-то одно, например, `read`, чтобы это соответствовало тому, как вы пишете в файл через `write`.

```
       new_data = old_data.replace(old_val, randval)
```

Вам нужно считанную строку превратить в число. После этого сложить его с новым случайным значением. Вы делаете что-то совсем не то.

```
       with open('values.bin', 'w') as f:
```

Вы открываете тот же файл ещё раз внутри блока `with`, т.е. не закрыв этот файл. Не делайте так. Закончите блок (уменьшите отступ), чтобы файл закрылся. И после этого только открывайте его опять.

```
            f.write(new_data)
            f.close()
```

Не нужно делать `close`, если вы пользуетесь менеджером контекста `with` для открытия файла. Он закроется сам автоматически, когда закончится блок кода.

Answer (score 0):

Если задача заключается в том чтобы записать в файл суму случайного числа с числом содержащимся в файле то попробуйте следующие:

```
with open('values.bin', 'r') as f:
     word = f.read()
     with open('values.bin', 'w') as f:
          f.write(str(int(word) + random.randint(3, 20)))
```

Comment: а как же сложение со старым значением из файла?

Comment: вы хочете старое значение файла записывать с старым и добовлять к нему случайное число ?

Comment: Не я , ТС хочет

Comment: тогда просто прочтите файл перед дозаписью запишите данное значение  в переменную и  конкатенируйте с новой строкой

Comment: как вы собираетесь складывать числа? конкатенируя строки? очень интересно.

Comment: @Dmitry я отредактировал ответ